# Stuck in a recursive directory search using os.scandir

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm searching through a large directory to sort an old archive into a specific order. I have embedded a function which is called recursively and when it finds a directory whose file path matches the search criteria it adds it to the 'found' dictionary `fdict`.

The expected outcome is that when the function is called on a directory with no subdirectories it completes with no actions and moves back up a level.

When run it gets stuck in the first directory it finds that contains no sub-directories and simply recursively calls the current directory for a search, getting stuck in a loop.

Below is the code abstract, any insight into why it is looping would be much appreciated.

```
def scan(queries, directory):
    fdict = {}
    def search(queries, directory, fdict):
        for entry in os.scandir(directory):
            if entry.is_dir():
                for x in queries:
                    if str(x) in entry.path:
                        fdict[str(x)] = entry.path
                        print("{} found and dicted".format(str(x)))
                    else:
                        search(queries, entry.path, fdict)
            else: pass
    search(queries, directory, fdict)
    return fdict
```

Comment: make sure you don't follow [symbolic links](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.is_symlink) Prehaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing can be written as

```
import os
# let qs be a list of queries [q]
# root be the start dir
for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    for dirname in dirnames:
        full_path = os.path.join(path, dirname) # optional (depends)
        for q in qs:
            if q in full_path:
                # do whatever
```

`os.walk` is recursive. You can do some `set` operation as well, to eliminate `for q in qs`. Comment if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to os.walk. I haven't previously used it and was using scandir for speed but having read up, it seems in 3.5 the scandir algorithm is used in walk. Could you quickly elabroate on the `set` operation you mention?

Comment: @GeorgeWorrall Thanks. about the `set` operations, I was alluding to a special case. which is say there exist a function `f`, such that `query = f(full_path)` which is to mean that all `full_path`s contain `query` in the same way. Then introduce a genexp `fulls = (f(p) for p in full_paths)`., then `matches = queries.intersection(fulls)`. Make those `set`s bdw.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it turns out the problem was in the `for x in queries:` statement.

The apparent loop was caused by bad design which meant that only the first value in the `queries` list compared to `entry.path` before the else statement was called and the search function called on the current entry.path.

Once a directory with no sub-directories was reached, it would then step back up one level and test the second entry in `queries` against entry.path.

Although the code would eventually produce the required result, this approach would take absolutely ages (in this instance `queries` is a 4000 value long list!) and gave the appearance of a loop on inspection.

Below is the corrected code for future reference if anyone stumbles across a similar problem.

```
def scan(queries, directory):
    fdict = {}
    def search(queries, directory, fdict):
        for entry in os.scandir(directory):
            if entry.is_dir():
                if entry.name in queries:
                    fdict[str(x)] = entry.path
                else:
                    time.sleep(2)
                    search(queries, entry.path, fdict)
            else: pass
    search(queries, directory, fdict)
    return fdict
```